# Таблица Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как реализовать таблицу такого формата на языке с++?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Самое первое - это нужно научиться выводить символы псевдографики. Тут все и просто и сложно. Если только под виндой и в их консоль, то тут можно использовать кодовую [таблицу 866](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP866) и выводите нужные символы (если редактор также в этой кодировке, то можно прямо копировать символы и вставлять, в противном случае лучше писать так `cout << "\xc0" <<endl;`, что бы вывести нижний левый уголок. Конечно, под это дело можно сделать констант). На этом первая часть задачи готова.

Теперь вторая часть - как вывести числа красиво. Тут поможет форматированный вывод. Можно конечно использовать printf, но это немного устаревшее. Для этого есть такая штука как [setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw). Как использовать. Выставляем нужное кол-во позиций с учетом левых пробелов, но без правых. А правые выводим сами.

Пример

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << "|" << setw(4) << i << "  ";
    }
    cout << "|" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

более сложный пример

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
        cout << string(43, '-') << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            cout << "|" << setw(4) << rand() % 100 << "  ";
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }
    cout << string(43, '-') << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**upd**

набросал пример, который в принципе реализует то что запрошено (на ideone.com отработает), но использует юникод. Код написан немного кривовато, но для идеи сойдет.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void line(string start, string middle, string cross, string end, int count, int len) {
    cout << start;
    for (int i = 0; i < count-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <len; j++) cout << middle;
        cout << cross;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <len; j++) cout << middle;
    cout << end << endl;
}

int main() {
    int last = 10;
    line("╔","═","╦","╗",6,6);
    cout << "║  N   ║   a  ║   b  ║   c  ║   d  ║ vetka║" << endl;
    line("╠","═","╬","╣",6,6);

    for (int l = 0; l < last; l++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            cout << "║" << setw(4) << rand() % 1000 << "  ";
        }
        cout << "║" << endl;

    }
    line("╚","═","╩","╝",6,6);

    return 0;
}
```